# How define dynamic Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function for replace or/and populate dinamic inputs. I paste one text in textarea and the function find input referenced and add the value. This works fine.

Bellow my code:

```
input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
                var content     = input.value;
                content.replace(/(\S+): ?(.+)/g, function(m, id, value) {
                    var field = $('input[data-alias-import="'+id+'"]');
                    var element = document.getElementById(field.attr('id'));

                    //console.log(element.attr('id'));
                    if (element) element.value = value;
                });
            });
```

In this case, the variable input is my textarea.

My question is, what the best way to make a same thing with a Select? How I can find a specific value in select and defined this "SELECTED".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the selected option of a select element you can use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$("#elementID :selected").val();
```